# Reflow large numbers of images (600+) smoothly

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, svg, reflow

I'm working on a webapp that populates a page with a large number of images.

It is similar in layout to an image search, in that the user chooses some settings at the top of the page and the page is instantly filled with images that correspond to her choice.

Sometimes up to 600+ images are generated in one callback. They are img elements with data uris that contain embedded svg.

My question is about performance. The Javascript itself completes very quickly, but once the 600 or so images have been added to the DOM, the browser can take up to FIFTEEN SECONDS to complete all the reflows. The browser freezes for this time, menus become unresponsive, and no change is shown until the reflows are complete. (Chromium version 66)

Is there a way for me to remove this bottleneck and make all the images reflow quicker? e.g a CSS approach that makes the layout trivial? If I made all the images the same size would that help?

If it can't be sped up, is there a way to make reflows happen without blocking user interaction with the page?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: The reason the browser was freezing during all the reflows was because my code was executing synchronously, and therefore tying up the browser.

Making the code asychronous by doing a `setTimeout(function, 0)` for each image, where `function` adds the image to the DOM, solved the problem.